# Show records having different colors

Tags: php, mysql

```
   $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM countries");
?>
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="htag">Countries List</h2>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <a href="addstudent.php" <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right ">Add New Country</button> </a>
     </div>
     </div>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php  }?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I am sorry If I have asked the question in a wrong way, I am new,
Actually I have the above query running properly and showing records from my sql database, and what i want now is to show 5 countries in red, next 5 in blue, and after that in green and the repeat again from red..
somebody help me with the logic and where to use it...
Thanks and Sorry once again.

Comment: What have you tried? This shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: You could look into using the [:nth-child()](http://nthmaster.com/) for a pure CSS solution.

Comment: check the [utility colors](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/colors/#color) on the official documentation it could help with your code

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
<?php
   $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM countries");
   $count = 0;
?>
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="htag">Countries List</h2>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <a href="addstudent.php" <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right ">Add New Country</button> </a>
     </div>
     </div>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
            if($count < 5) { $color = 'class="table-danger"'; $count = 0;} else { $color = 'class="table-info"';}
            $count++;
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td <?php echo $color ?> ><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php  }?>
        </tbody>
  </table>
```

from what I saw you are using bootstrap 4 then I added the classes referring to the colors.

please test and see if it works.